# How to plot across several layout regions

Tags: r, plot

There are times when I am composing a multi-part figure, and I have a complex layout, and I would like to plot outside of the box.  (I say this figuratively and literally).

Consider this example using the `R` base graphics function `layout()` to set a complex layout:

```
## Define the layout regions
multiPartFigureLayout <- structure(c(4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 8, 8, 
                                         5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 8, 8, 
                                         9, 9, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 8, 8, 
                                         6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 8, 8, 
                                         7, 7, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 8, 8), 
                                         .Dim = c(10L, 5L))

## Demonstrate the layout
win.graph(4, 5)
layout(multiPartFigureLayout)
layout.show(9)
```

This produces the following plotting layout.  (I have added text in red using image editing software)

[image]

This is one application of plotting outside the box: overprinting text in the area shown.  Equally, it might be necessary to overprint another graphical element.  For example, to draw a rule that spans the boxes.

I am aware that it is possible to expand the `multiPartFigureLayout` matrix and add a plotting region above that could hold the text or the rule.  But I don't want to do this:  I want to overprint it across multiple layout regions.

Is there a way to use base graphics to do this, either using a feature for this purpose, or by tricking the plotting functions in some way?

Comment: I guess we have different meanings attached to the word "plotting". I think of the points, lines and curves as "plotting" and the addtion of legends and text as "annotation". But it's your question.

Comment: I appreciated your answer @DWin, correct and useful.  But I thought I should expand it a bit to make it more useful to others.  See my edit regarding plotting other graphical elements (e.g. rules).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw things that extend beyond the current plot set `par(xpd=NA)`.  You can use the functions `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` to convert between different coordinate systems.

You can save a location from one plot by converting to 'ndc' coordinates, then convert from those to user coordinates in another plot, you can also use these functions to find the coordinates relative to the current plot, figure, or device for passing to other functions.  An example:

```
layout( matrix( c(1,2,3,2), 2 ) )
par(xpd=NA)
with(iris, plot(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, col=Species) )
save1.x <- grconvertX( 0.25, from='npc', to='ndc' )
save2.x <- grconvertX( iris$Sepal.Width[1], to='ndc' )
save2.y <- grconvertY( iris$Sepal.Length[1], to='ndc' )
with(iris, plot(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, col=Species) )
with(iris, arrows( Petal.Width[1], Petal.Length[1], 
   grconvertX( save2.x, from='ndc' ), 
   grconvertY( save2.y, from='ndc' ), col='orange' ) )
with( iris, plot( Petal.Length, Sepal.Length, col=Species ) )
segments( grconvertX( 0.75, from='npc' ), grconvertY(0.9, from='npc'),
   grconvertX( save1.x, from='ndc'), col='purple' )
```

Comment: With `par(xpd=NA)` combined with these lesser-known functions, the entire device is yours for the plotting.  Very nice.

Answer (score 4):

```
mtext("even longer test of overplotting to see if it extends across the plots" , line=-1, col="red")
?mtext
```

`mtext` can annotate inside and across boundaries of graphics regions if you use negative 'line' values. (The side argument to `mtext` defaults to 3 (="top"). If you were to try using `text` you would find that it had difficulty extending past a region boundary.  I tried with `xpd=TRUE` as an argument `text` to get but did not succeed. Perhaps using it with `par()` prior to the `text` call would allow it to work.